# remove a part in array value without foreach

Tags: arrays, perl

For example I have this array

```
my @a = ("http://aze.com/azfaz", "http://acc.com/azfssz");
```

I want to remove the `azfaz`/`azfssz` part in the URLs without using `foreach`

I made this subroutine to remove the last section after the 3 slash `/` characters

```
sub cheat {
    my @o = split( /\//, $_[0], 3 );
    my @r = split( /\//, $o[2], 0 );
    return $r[0];
}
```

When I call `cheat(@a)` it just removes the `azfaz` from the first site in array and it's not working for the other

Answer (score 7):

You should use the [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) module for manipulating URL strings

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use URI;

my @a = qw< http://aze.com/azfaz  http://acc.com/azfssz >;

sub host_name {
  return map { URI->new($_)->host } @_;
}

say for host_name @a;
```

#### output

```
aze.com
acc.com
```

Answer (score 3):

`$_[0]` just refers to the first element in the array you pass to `cheat`. Your processing algorithm looks correct, you just need to apply it to all of the elements in `@_`. There are many ways to iterate over a list to produce another list. `map` is often a good way:

```
sub cheat {
    return map {
        my @o = split(/\//,$_,3);          # split on $_, not $_[0]
        my @r = split (/\//,$o[2],0);
        $r[0];                             # add to map output, don't return
    } @_;
}
```

Or you could keep your existing `cheat` function and run `map` outside the function.

```
@fixed_array = map { cheat($_) } @array;
```

`foreach` would work too -- but you seem reluctant to use it for some reason.